# Firestore Cloud Function Array Loop - Writes Long Delay

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function which loops through an array of uids and then creates a write for each one. Normal writes happen almost instantly but here there is a long lag before the writes show up.

I have tried on array of different sizes. An array with just one or two uids is faster but still has a lag of about 5-6 seconds.

```
exports.addPostings = functions.firestore
    .document('posts/{postID}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newValue = snap.data();
    var uid = newValue.author.uid;
    let followers = [];
    var feedRef = db.collection("feedItems");
    var authorRef = db.collection("users").doc(newValue.author.uid);
    authorRef.get().then((doc) => {
        let data = doc.data();
        let post_count = data.postCount;
        authorRef.update({
            postCount: Number(post_count) + 1
        }).then(() => {
            authorRef.collection('followers').doc('content').get().then((doc) => {
                let data = doc.data();
                if (typeof data.uids != 'undefined') {
                    followers = data.uids;
                }
            }).then(() => {
                followers.forEach((fol) => {
                  feedRef.add({
                      createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), uid: fol, creatorUid: uid,
                      postId: context.params.postID, isResharedPost: false, wasViewed: false,
                      wasReshared: false, wasLiked: false, wasDirectlyShared: false
                  });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you considering the thing denominated `cold start` in cloud functions? When your function hasn't been executed in some time, Cloud Functions puts it in a mode that uses fewer resources. So the very first calls after deploys are going to be very slow.

Comment: How long would a cold start last ?

Comment: Up to 10 seconds sometimes. It depends on various factors. But after a couple of calls your function should be responding just in time.

Comment: ok, so then I don't think that is the issue. I will try using batch and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several points you should modify in your code:

1. You are not returning the promises returned by the asynchronous methods, **which is key when writing Cloud Function code**, as explained in the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the official Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/
2. You should correctly chain the promises
3. You should use a batched write, as indicated by CuriousGeorge

The following modifications should do the trick (not tested however!):

```
exports.addPostings = functions.firestore
  .document('posts/{postID}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const newValue = snap.data();
    var uid = newValue.author.uid;
    let followers = [];
    var feedRef = db.collection('feedItems');
    var authorRef = db.collection('users').doc(newValue.author.uid);

    return authorRef
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        let data = doc.data();
        let post_count = data.postCount;
        return authorRef.update({
          postCount: Number(post_count) + 1
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return authorRef
          .collection('followers')
          .doc('content')
          .get();
      })
      .then(doc => {
        let data = doc.data();
        if (typeof data.uids != 'undefined') {
          followers = data.uids;

          let batch = db.batch();

          followers.forEach(fol => {
            const ref = feedRef.doc();
            batch.set(ref, {
              createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              uid: fol,
              creatorUid: uid,
              postId: context.params.postID,
              isResharedPost: false,
              wasViewed: false,
              wasReshared: false,
              wasLiked: false,
              wasDirectlyShared: false
            });
          });

          // Commit the batch
          return batch.commit();
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try

Comment: Works instantly ! Just wondering if the batch has to write more than 500, what happens ?

Comment: Hey, I am trying to solve the same issue in a similar function but am having issues there. Do you think you can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833485/firestore-cloud-function-trying-to-use-a-batch-to-group-writes-and-missing-retur

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should look into using transactions.batched writes here. This allows you to define a series of read/writes then execute them all at the same time. Part of the reason this method may be slow is that you are executing multiple read/writes (and this is also bad in case of failure in the middle of processing). https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions